# Modelling IF/THEN statements in Linear Programming

Tags: linear-programming

Given a set of boolean variables X = {x0,x1, .... xn}, where each variable x\in X belongs to one group G = {g0, g1, ..., gm}, g \subset X.

The objective of the problem is to maximize the number of variables in X that are set to 1.

How can I model the constraint in LP that requires ALL the variables belonging to the same group g\in G to be set to EITHER 0 or to 1? More precisely, no two boolean variables from a g\in G can have different values.

P.S: The above defined problem is just a simplification of the real problem, which includes additional constraints aside from the one defined above.

Answer (score 0):

Such constraints are not convex and thus cannot be formulated as LP. However it is a case of **[ILP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) (Integer LP), that is NP task**, but in practice it can be solved for reasonable number of variables.

You can even quite easily extend the LP task to ILP by constraining `0 <= x <= 1` and when the optimum is not either 0 or 1, you solve two LPs, one with fixing x to 0, the other to 1 and pick the better one. You repeat (recurse) until all your integer conditions are met. (For details or some more efficient ways use Google).

---

**Edit**: Given your specific problem assignment, why would't you just put all variables equal to 1? That is obviously the maximum, and for all possible groups it holds that no two values are different (since all are 1s).